# Is there a way to save a model with hyperparameters and weights both after hyperparameter tuning and model training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hyperparameters

I am using keras_tuner's Hyperband for hyperparameter tuning and it creates about 30 folders for all it's trials. So what I have to do right now is first create the model with all the hyperparameters and then load it's weights from checkpoints.

I want to find a way that utilizes less space because I have to do this for about 1k entities and train a different model for them all.

My current method of loading a saved model:

```
best_hps = tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]
my_model= tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)
my_model.load_weights(filepath).expect_partial()
```

My only problem is each model takes a lot of space because of it's hyperparameter tuning.
Can I save the model fully with weights and hyperparameters.

I tried [keras's save_model and load_model](https://keras.io/api/saving/model_saving_and_loading/) and even tried saving the trained model as h5 file but none of them worked.

Is there something I'm missing? How can I solve this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried [keras's "save_model" and load_model](https://keras.io/api/saving/model_saving_and_loading/) and even tried saving the trained model as h5 file but none of them worked.

If your hypermodel has complex architectures or involves custom layers or functions, then when you save just the weights and try to rebuild the model from scratch, you will need to ensure that the new model's architecture matches the architecture of the saved weights *exactly*.

An easier approach would be to save the *entire* model (architecture + weights): that essentially encapsulates everything, which minimizes the risk of architecture mismatch during loading.
Here, using the [`model.fit()` method](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#fit-method):

```py
tuner = Hyperband(
    build_model,
    objective='val_loss',
    max_epochs=10,
    factor=3,
    directory='my_dir',
    project_name='helloworld')
tuner.search(x, y, epochs=50, validation_data=(val_x, val_y))

best_hps = tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]

model = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=50, validation_data=(val_x, val_y))

model.save("best_model.h5")
```

Note that, when saving the entire model, if it contains custom layers or loss functions, you need to provide those when loading the model. But this is true for your initial method as well.

```py
loaded_model = load_model("best_model.h5", custom_objects={'CustomLayer': CustomLayer})
```

Now, saving the entire model might use more space than saving just the weights, but the advantage is that you encapsulate the entire trained model: architecture, optimizer, weights, and even the training configuration.

And the additional `model.fit()` step in the proposed approach is to ensure the model is trained with the best hyperparameters before saving. But if you have already trained the model during the tuning process, this step may be redundant. The core idea was to highlight that after building the model with the best hyperparameters, you should train it (if not already done) before saving.

---

> Can I save hyperband selections as keras serializable objects? My model is built like this:
>
> ```
> hp_units = hp.Int('units', min_value=100, max_value=300, step=30) 
> my_layer=tf.keras.layers.LSTM(hp_units,return_sequences=True)(raw_features)
> ```

If you are facing issues where hyperparameters with their names are not recognized while deserializing the model, it might be because of complex or custom model architectures.

Not that I know of: I do not see a direct way to serialize the [Hyperband selection (the tuner)](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/keras_tuner#instantiate_the_tuner_and_perform_hypertuning) as a Keras object, because [Keras serialization utilities are mainly designed for models](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load), not tuners.

Keras Tuner's Hyperband tuner itself is not a Keras model but a tuning algorithm that helps to find the best hyperparameters for a given model. It directly fit into the model serialization framework provided by Keras.

> The main problem while saving and loading these models is that hyperparameters with their names are not recognized while deserializing the object

You might consider an approach where you [save the only the weight](https://keras.io/api/saving/weights_saving_and_loading/) and the [model config](https://keras.io/guides/serialization_and_saving/#apis) separately.
That can be applied to your LSTM model, which uses a hyperparameter for its units.

The Keras Tuner stores the hyperparameters and trial results in the directory specified when you instantiate the tuner. You can use the [`get_best_hyperparameters` method](https://keras.io/api/keras_tuner/tuners/base_tuner/) to get the best hyperparameters after tuning.

First, you perform hyperparameter tuning, train your model with the best hyperparameters, and then save both the model weights and hyperparameters.

```py
from keras_tuner.engine.hyperparameters import HyperParameters
import tensorflow as tf

# After hyperparameter tuning, retrieve the best hyperparameters.
best_hps = tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]

# Use these best hyperparameters to build your LSTM model.
units_optimal = best_hps.get('units') # Get the optimal number of units.
my_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units_optimal, return_sequences=True)(raw_features)

# Continue building your model and compile it.
model.compile(...) # Replace with your compile statement

# Now train your model.
model.fit(x, y, epochs=50, validation_data=(val_x, val_y))

# After training, save your model's weights.
model.save_weights("best_model_weights.h5")

# Save the hyperparameters separately to a JSON file.
with open('hyperparameters.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(best_hps.get_config())
```

Once you have saved your model weights and hyperparameters, you can reload them when needed:

```py
from keras_tuner.engine.hyperparameters import HyperParameters
import tensorflow as tf

# Load the hyperparameters from the JSON file.
with open('hyperparameters.json', 'r') as f:
    hps_config = f.read()

# Convert the JSON string back to a HyperParameters object.
best_hps = HyperParameters.from_config(hps_config)

# Use the reloaded hyperparameters to build the same LSTM model.
units_optimal = best_hps.get('units') # Get the optimal number of units.
my_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units_optimal, return_sequences=True)(raw_features)

# Continue building your model and compile it.
model.compile(...) # Replace with your compile statement

# Load the previously saved weights into your model.
model.load_weights("best_model_weights.h5")
```

Do replace `model.compile(...)` with your actual model compile statements. If there are additional layers or operations in your model, they should be added in both saving and loading codes accordingly.

That way, you separate the saving and loading of model weights and hyperparameters. The saved hyperparameters are used to recreate the same model architecture before loading the model weights.
That might also help if your model is complex or involves custom functions that might not be serialized properly when saving the full model.

Comment: Can I save hyperband selections as keras serializable objects?
My model is built like this?
hp_units = hp.Int('units', min_value=100, max_value=300, step=30)
 my_layer=tf.keras.layers.LSTM(hp_units,return_sequences=True)(raw_features)

Comment: The main problem while saving and loading these models is that hyperparameters with their names are not recognized while deserializing the object

Comment: @KhushiMehta Not that I know of: I do not see a direct way to serialize the [Hyperband selection (the tuner)](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/keras_tuner#instantiate_the_tuner_and_perform_hypertuning) as a Keras object, because Keras [serialization utilities are mainly designed for models](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load), not tuners.

Keras Tuner's Hyperband tuner itself is not a Keras model but a tuning algorithm that helps to find the best hyperparameters for a given model.  
It directly fit into the model serialization framework provided by Keras.

Comment: @KhushiMehta "The main problem while saving and loading these models is that hyperparameters with their names are not recognized while deserializing the object": I have edited the answer to propose an alternative approach.